# Does Sitecore Web Forms For Marketers rely on cloning?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, web-forms-for-marketers

We're running Sitecore 7.2 (rev. 150408) with Web Forms for Marketers module 2.4 rev.141008

Due to performance issues with clones in this version of 7.2 we have been reccomended to disable cloning.

However, when running a query to find cloned items, I found that the /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Web Forms for Marketers Conditions/Conditions item, with multiple child items, was a clone of the /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Obsolete/Conditional Renderings/Conditions item

Can this be safely uncloned, or does WFFM rely on the clone relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On https://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%202,-d-,4/Module_Upgrades/230_131126_to_24_140117.aspx you can find this:

> Due to changes of Rules item structure in CMS 7.1 two collisions are
>   expected during update installation:
>
> Cannot delete item '/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Web Forms for
>   Marketers Conditions' because it has children. Cannot delete item
>   '/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Web Forms for Marketers
>   Conditions/Actions' because it has children. To prevent removing user
>   defined Conditions or Actions for WFFM we do not remove old WFFM
>   structure, so the user can handle this personally.

So it seems the folder "/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Web Forms for Marketers Conditions" was used in version 2.3, and has been removed in version 2.4. Unless you have some custom rules in the folder, it should be safe to delete it.